# Consultas de base de datos

Tags: sql, mariadb

> Buenas noches.  Estoy tratando de realizar algunas consultas pero algunas me salen con error o que el "conjunto esta vacio"

Estas son las tablas

```
create table recepcionista(Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
 Nombre_re varchar(20) not null,
 A_pre varchar(30) not null,
 A_mre varchar(30) not null,
 telefono varchar(15) not null,
primary key(Clav_re));



create table cliente(Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Clav_re varchar(10) not null,
Nombre_cli varchar(25) not null,
A_pcli varchar(25) not null,
A_mcli varchar(25) not null,
Telefono_cli varchar(15) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli),
index(Clav_re),
FOREIGN KEY(Clav_re)
REFERENCES recepcionista(Clav_re)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


 create table servicio (
Id_ser varchar(10) not null,
Tipo_ser varchar(25) not null,
Fecha date not null,
primary key(Id_ser));



create table cliSer (
Id_cli varchar(10),
Id_ser varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Id_cli,Id_ser),
INDEX (Id_cli),
INDEX(Id_ser),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli) REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Id_ser) REFERENCES servicio(Id_ser)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);



create table habitacion (
Id_hab varchar(10) not null,
Id_cli varchar(10) not null,
Num_hab int(10) not null,
Num_piso int(10) not null,
Dias int(10) not null,
Precio int(10) not null,
Tip_hab varchar(20) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id_hab),
index(Id_cli),
FOREIGN KEY(Id_cli)
REFERENCES cliente(Id_cli)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Y ACA ESTAN LAS CONSULTAS QUE ME FALLAN

```
 MariaDB [hotelx]> select Nombre_re from cliente, recepcionista where recepcionista.Clav_re = cliente.Clav_re and A_pcli = 'Mujica';
    Empty set (0.001 sec)



    MariaDB [hotelx]> select Id_cli from cliente, servicio where cliente.Id_cli = servicio.Id_ser and Fecha = 2019-01-19;
    Empty set (0.000 sec)



    MariaDB [hotelx]> select Nombre_cli, Fecha, Tipo_ser, Nombre_re from cliente, servicio, recepcionista where cliente.Id_cli = servicio.Id_ser and
        ->  servicio.Id_ser = recepcionista.Clav_re;
    Empty set (0.001 sec)
```

Estos son los datos

```
INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT01','Juan','Osorio','Perez',914456435);

INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT02','Javier','Sanchez','Juan',917845120);

INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT03','Luis','Baez','Gumecindo',914152639);

INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT04','Juana','Gonzalez','Molina',911028912);

INSERT INTO recepcionista(Clav_re,Nombre_re,A_pre,A_mre,telefono) VALUES
('RT05','Martha','Martinez','Romero',915623829);



INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT01','RT01','Lalo','Perez','Perez',914456435);
INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT02','RT02','Ramiro','Fernandez','Huerta',985623021);
INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT03','RT02','Edgar','Julio','Vazquez',963215478);
INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT04','RT03','Jazmin','Masegoza','Dorantes',912365474);
INSERT INTO cliente(Id_cli,Clav_re,Nombre_cli,A_pcli,A_mcli,telefono_cli) VALUES
('CT05','RT03','Claudia','Guerrero','Mujica',9236541205);



INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST01','restaurante','2000-10-22');
INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST02','gimnasio','2019-10-05');
INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST03','restaurante','2018-05-14');
INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST04','restaurante','2000-10-22');
INSERT INTO servicio(Id_ser,Tipo_ser,Fecha) VALUES
('ST05','gimnasio','2019-01-19');




INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES 
('CT01','ST01');
INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES 
('CT02','ST02'),
INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES 
('CT03','ST03');
INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES 
('CT04','ST04');
INSERT INTO cliSer(Id_cli,Id_ser) VALUES 
('CT05','ST05');




INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H01','CT01',01,2,1,1200,'sencilla');

INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H02','CT02',42,3,2,2000,'estandar');

INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H03','CT03',03,2,1,2000,'estandar');

INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H04','CT04',15,2,1,3500,'suite');

INSERT INTO habitacion(Id_hab,Id_cli,Num_hab,Num_piso,Dias,Precio,Tip_hab) VALUES
('H05','CT05',02,2,1,1200,'sencilla');
```

Comment: Y lo siento no supe como poner un identificador de lenguaje ya que soy nueva en Stack overflow

Comment: si si tengo ,lo que pasa que no conozco bien la pagina y no puedo subir foto, intentaré agregar los datos aunque se vean muy juntos

Comment: ok, te comento que cuando pegues código para darle formato debes: **seleccionarlo y presionar `ctrl + k` o seleccionarlo y presionar el ícono `{}`**

Comment: Si muchas gracias Aprendiz ya le puse formato

Comment: Si claro, quiero obtener lo siguiente

Comment: Listar el nombre de recepcionista que atendió a los clientes con apellido materno Mujica:
select Nombre_re from recepcionista, cliente where recepcionista.Clav_re = cliente.Clav_re and A_pcli = 'Mujica';

Comment: Listar el id cliente y la fecha en que realizó el servicio: select Id_cli from cliente, servicio where cliente.Id_cli = servicio.Id_ser and Fecha = 2019-01-19;

Comment: Es que no se como entrar a la tabla "recepcionista"

Comment: Si muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Primera consulta:
>
> El campo `A_mcli` para el apellido  `'Mujica'`

```
select Nombre_re 
from cliente, recepcionista 
where recepcionista.Clav_re = cliente.Clav_re and A_mcli = 'Mujica'
```

> Segunda consulta: Faltaba relacionar la tabla `cliser`
>   `cliser.Id_cli=cliente.Id_cli AND cliser.Id_ser=servicio.Id_ser` y
>   comillas a: `'2019-01-19'`

```
select cliente.Id_cli 
from cliente, servicio, cliser 
where cliser.Id_cli=cliente.Id_cli AND cliser.Id_ser=servicio.Id_ser and Fecha = '2019-01-19';
```

> Tercera consulta: La relacion: `servicio.Id_ser = recepcionista.Clav_r`e
>    estaba mal pues no existia y era: 
>   `cliente.Clav_re =recepcionista.Clav_re;`

```
select Nombre_cli, Fecha, Tipo_ser, Nombre_re 
from cliente, servicio, recepcionista , cliser 
WHERE cliser.Id_cli=cliente.Id_cli AND cliser.Id_ser=servicio.Id_ser AND cliente.Clav_re = recepcionista.Clav_re;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias santiago, agradezco su tiempo y apoyo, si ya estan bien mis consultas, gracias

Comment: No te olvides dar por solucionado la pregunta.Es un gusto ayudar.

Comment: Si claro, aunque ahorita no puedo votar ya que no tengo ese privilegio, y gracias muy amable, para dar la respuesta por solucionada es en la palomita que se pone verde verdad?

Comment: Si  Aurora, saludos :)

Comment: Saludos, ya lo hice , gracias